# React Native ListView won't render with Redux Saga data

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, redux-saga

I am having bit of wrinkle in my React Native project. I have successfully deployed Redux Saga into the project and got my required data into the reducers. I then used mapStateToProps to bring the data back into my React component. The data has successfully arrived into the component. However, the problem appears when I pass the data(array) into `dataSource.cloneWithRows(launchAppReducer.data)` it doesn't process the data as it should be in order to render it on the UI.

Following is the code I am using and I also have attached my console.log() screenshot if it helps to get down to the problem here.

[image]

```
    class Mobile extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        let { readPostsAction } = this.props;
        readPostsAction();
      }

      render() {
        let { data } = this.props;
        return (
          <Container>
            <ListView
              dataSource={data}
              renderRow={
                (rowData) =>
                  <View>

                  </View>
              }
            />
          </Container>
        );
      }
    }

    const dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });

    function mapStateToProps({ launchAppReducer }) {
      return {
        isLoading: launchAppReducer.isLoading,
        data: dataSource.cloneWithRows(launchAppReducer.data)
      }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, { readPostsAction: actions.readPostsAction })(Mobile);
```

Comment: `ListView` has been [deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html), use `Flatlist` or `SectionList`, and check if the error still persists

Comment: I did FlatList a go and the result are exactly same as for the ListView. It doesn't throw any error neither it shows a warning, just a plain screen which is why it is making it harder to debug the issue it might be having here.

Comment: To narrow it down, I did a demo array and passed it to the Flastlist and it works as expected, however it is not rending out the data made available from Redux-Saga props, any thoughts on this please would be appreciated?

Comment: I might need to check your code for this one, can you create a sample repo please?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have it published on GitHub, link to the screen which is in question right now is here;https://github.com/Taimoormk/discovestan-redux-saga/blob/master/src/screens/Mobile.js

Comment: Got it, I'll have a look at it soon.

Comment: Hi Is this issue solved??
I faced a similar issue. Help will be appreciated. Great day